# Why does piping yt-dlp tp FFmpeg fail with --download-sections?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, youtube-dl, yt-dlp

I'm trying to download a clip of a video (including audio) in a **streaming** manner (i.e. with ***no temporary files***) in a given format.

This works fine:

```
yt-dlp --ignore-config --no-config-locations -f 22 -o - a3ICNMQW7Ok |
  ffmpeg -i - -c copy -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -f mp4 -y temp.mp4
```

But this fails:

```
yt-dlp --ignore-config --no-config-locations -f 22 -o - a3ICNMQW7Ok --download-sections "*0-30" |
  ffmpeg -i - -c copy -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -f mp4 -y temp.mp4
```

> `[mp4 @ 0x7fffb806f200]` Malformed AAC bitstream detected:
> use the audio bitstream filter `aac_adtstoasc` to fix it (`-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc` option with ffmpeg)

I don't understand how this can happen. What is going on and how do I fix it?

(And no, `-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc` doesn't solve the problem, because if I use it, there is no longer any audio when I play the downloaded video.)

Comment: The issue is not reproducible. A file named `temp.mp4` is created with video resolution 1280x720 at 29.97fps, with AVC codec, and stereo audio with sample rate 44.1KHz and AAC codec (MeidaInfo shows AAC LC codec). My yt-dlp version is `2022.07.18`, FFmpeg version is `4.4.1-full_build-www.gyan.dev` (using Windows 10). Try executing `yt-dlp -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3ICNMQW7Ok` and select a specific source as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486297/how-to-select-video-quality-from-youtube-dl). I could be that some formats works and other doesn't.

Comment: @Rotem: Ah wow, thanks for pointing this out. I hard-coded the format now; you should be able to reproduce it with the given command line.

Comment: It looks like re-encoding the audio is required: `yt-dlp --ignore-config --no-config-locations -f 22 -o - a3ICNMQW7Ok --download-sections "*0-30" | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec copy -acodec aac -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -f mp4 -y temp.mp4` (something to do with `--download-sections "*0-30"`) using `"0-30"` we don't have to re-encode the audio, but using `"*0-30"`, we do have to re-encoded the audio (note: In my first comment I missed the part that says the the first command works but the second does not).

Comment: Compare the result of: `yt-dlp --ignore-config --no-config-locations -f 22 -o - a3ICNMQW7Ok --download-sections "*0-30" > 1.mp4` and `yt-dlp --ignore-config --no-config-locations -f 22 -o tmp a3ICNMQW7Ok --download-sections "0-30" > 2.mp4`. It looks like `1.mp` is downloaded with menu (and has some extra headers). I guess we can't have menu without moov atom. The following command works: `yt-dlp --ignore-config --no-config-locations -f 22 -o - a3ICNMQW7Ok --download-sections "*0-30" | ffmpeg -i - -c copy -movflags frag_keyframe -f mp4 -y temp.mp4` (it could be a bug in FFmpeg).

Comment: @Rotem: Interesting. It seems to throw off the playback slider in my media player somehow, but it does play. Thanks for the info.